# meaning of the phrase "sound about right"?

Tags: meaning

I have heard it in this [video](https://youtu.be/CK4OrYTsf-Q). It is at 2 minute and 19 second. Here is the context:

> [Gill] So, David, you have been here for a while now, haven't you?
>
> [David] Yes.
>
> [Gill] I remember the place gradually being decorated and open.
>
> [David] Yeah, well, we met I would imagine sometime around about May 2015 and we opened in July 2015.
>
> [Gill] Right, That **sounds about right**.

Does Gill mean that she is not completely sure if the date was right for opening?

Comment: **about** can mean "in the general vicinity of".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Sounds about right" can be used when the person is mostly sure of something, but could be wrong. Adding "about" could indicate a little bit of uncertainty over "sounds right"

Answer (score 2):

"Does Gill mean that she is not completely sure if the date was right for opening?" Correct - she is not sure - but there is more to it than just that.

I have always taken "That sounds about right" to mean that (in response to another person's assessment of something) the speaker is satisfied with that assessment, and sees it as sufficiently accurate to allow it to stand. 
Also that the speaker (the one saying "That sounds about right") feels s/he could not provide a more accurate assessment themselves. Further, it's a way of signaling that the point in question is not important enough for further discussion: "Let's move on."